# How do I query a GitHub Project V2 Item Order by Custom Field from GraphQL?

Tags: github, graphql, github-api, github-graphql

How do I get the order of items in a board view column from the API? I found the `sortBy` object in the `ProjectV2` `views`, but I'm struggling querying the `items` ordered by `fieldValue` (position?).

Would you mind helping me construct a query for the JSON equivalent of the data in the picture, please?

[image]

Comment: I also asked the same question in the [Github Community](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73651004/how-do-i-query-a-github-project-v2-item-order-by-custom-field-from-graphql), just in case

Comment: Did you work this out Adam?

Comment: Hey, Ben, I did not. But I suspect there might not be such a thing as Order in Column in Github Projects V2 data design at all. I think there's only an Order of Items in the entire Project and the column is "view" in the scope of the Field Value.

Comment: What I did:
    - created custom select field A with options A1, A2, A3
    - created custom select field B with options  B1, B2, B3
    - created two different boards, columns by A and B options
    - created three Items (cards) "One", "Two", "Three", all with custom Field A value A1, custom Field B value B1
    - reordered the items in the board A
    - the order is the `Items` node order in the GrapQL API
    - BUT the order propagated to the board B
    - when I reorder the items in the board B
    - the order propagates to the board A and again to the Items order in the API